# Hybris Accelerator site get's session time out

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If we are not hitting the site for a long time,it says cms site not found.And then if we need to give the full url. i.e localhost:9001/acceleratorstorefront/?site=electronics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Session contains the cmsSite (or web site in other words). this value is used as long as the session is alive. When the session expires, the cmssite value doesn't exist anymore, and you should provide it, by following one of the url patterns related to the site you wanna display (which is in your case `localhost:9001/acceleratorstorefront/?site=electronics`

Please check the CmsSiteFilter, it contains all the code responsible for that behavior.

Comment: do not use localhost, use the hosts file approach

Comment: @Stretch : Using the hosts file or not has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: yes, it does... do NOT use the localhost , site= approach.

Answer (score 1):

That is because Session timeout has been set in your `accelerator` storefront web.xml file.
Hybris filter set that values in Session and this is being used when you hot any button.

Session timeout is a common thing, just look inside web.xml for Session timeout setting and you can increase it to anything you want for testing and development.

Comment: You have missed the Jalo session config.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a url that matches one of the urlPatterns on the CMSSite.

Go HMC > WCMS > Websites, look under the Configuration section of the Properties tab.

By default you should use http://electronics.local:9001/yacceleratorstorefront/ and map that host in your hosts file.

Using ?site=electronics sets the Site in the Session, so when this expires you will need to set that again of course. This is done automatically for you when matching against a urlPattern.